# CORS İframe could not use Asp.net SessionId

Tags: asp.net, cookies, iframe, cross-domain

Set-cookie asp.net_sessionId exists on login response but Asp.net sessionId is different on second iframe src request :(

is this problem about CORS? How could I fix it?

**Login Request**

**Request:**
http://10.215.147.180:8080/Webshell/Home/Login
POST
Referer: http://localhost:4200/authentication/login

**Response:**
**set-cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=lgepjmyn4kgml5qaa3eg5fur; path=/; HttpOnly
set-cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=lgepjmyn4kgml5qaa3eg5fur; expires=Thu, 18-Jul-2019 02:32:23 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly**
set-cookie: AuhtenticationCookieName=Qmp00tyk_Y2txvq-Z-VkjhcYJJkOInIHQFMR2-L6uW0wuk8PeMfceTHI5CpvPS2iE-f6tlb8qsWibzUhZA33JQVtRkYOMGr9vuGgZEkyUu2yllMTb-5_I97qzLcndcT9qbS67PKPWUllBK9V3nubtXG21wAe4XVpJMgNBgYdug2XuMzsaeqT3vq64-iH8KaFhOcYoX_qC8B1J-DNcYBcG7QIATm1uz_O1LhBS7U65CEgiveIdt7GOO9zGEErqSitxJDwUjJUHrPnTaWgwTIJP2G8CwrrDsSSWeGCzJhd6uEOiiAR82-CHCzqtjOu-qoTP6WsjfVFr-7Httz0dNuKs1O6o5tEpXTbvFwgHHDL-8lN9pJyW5aUmvNNWuvcn3Sd77L5sHnlahxX-1alPMpTig; path=/; expires=Wed, 17-Jul-2019 14:52:23 GMT; HttpOnly
x-aspnetmvc-version: 5.2
x-aspnet-version: 4.0.30319
x-sourcefiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcRmFjZVByb2plY3RzXEFrYmFua0ZhY2UuQnJhbmNoQmFua2luZ1xERVZcU3JjXENvcmVcVUlcQXBwXFdlYnNoZWxsXEhvbWVcTG9naW4=?=
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
x-content-type-options: nosniff
access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:4200
access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type
**access-control-allow-credentials: true**

**Iframe Src Request**
http://10.215.147.180:8080/singlesignon/tabsignon

Host: 10.215.147.180:8080
**Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=ldedb4oynvhrpw4wac5lirzd**
Referer: http://localhost:4200/shell/apps
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem with "withCredentials: true"